# Open current video in YouTube app from Firefox

Tags: youtube, firefox-for-android

From a youtube.com page open in Firefox, is there a straight-forward way to open the video using the YouTube app?

Firefox version 43.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may be a solution. You can make the video open in the YouTube app when you press the little Android icon in the right corner of the address bar while you're on the site!

[image: See this]

Comment: Is there any way to not have to go through this extra step and just have Firefox open the native app when you click on the YouTube link like the Chrome browser does?

Answer (score 2):

Well I have another answer. There's an extension on Firefox called [Open Native App](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/open-native-app/), which as the name suggests, opens things in their native apps.

From its "About this add-on"

> A simple extension I created after getting frustrated with my device opening native links in Firefox rather than it's native app. Creates a menu option in your Firefox menu called "Open in Native App" which will trigger the Android intent app chooser for the link currently open.
>
> This is confirmed working for the following:
>
> - Play Store (play.google.com)
> - YouTube (youtube.com)
> - IMDB (imdb.com)
> - Wikipedia (wikipedia.org)
> - Foursquare (foursquare.com)
>
> Not working for:
>
> - Tumblr (tumblr.com)
> - Google+ (plus.google.com)
> - Facebook (facebook.com)